# How do I reference table dot column notation in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

```
SELECT * from meets
 LEFT JOIN teams as hteam on meets.meet_hometeam=hteam.team_id 
 LEFT JOIN teams as ateam on meets.meet_awayteam=ateam.team_id 
 LEFT JOIN teams as altloc on (meets.meet_altloc=altloc.team_id and meets.meet_altloc!='')
 where meet_date between ($now+(4*86400)) and ($now+(5*86400) or meets.meet_id='2')
```

In PHP:

```
$var = $queryvar->fetch_object();
```

I'm having issues when I call `$var->ateam.team_town` it is just treating the dot as concatenation and not as an object to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `SELECT *` when doing `JOIN` or `UNION` queries. Instead, be specific about the columns you need, and if columns have the same name in different tables, you need to assign aliases to them.

Aside from the *necessity* of differentiating columns with similar names, you get the benefit of being deterministic about the order in which they're returned and protection from future schema changes that add columns you *don't want* from being automatically pulled into this (like image blob data or something).

```
SELECT
  /* specify columns from each table with aliases */
  hteam.team_id AS hometeam_id,
  ateam.team_id AS awayteam_id,
  hteam.team_town AS hometeam_town,
  ateam.team_town AS awayteam_town,
  ...
  ...
  etc...
FROM meets
 LEFT JOIN teams as hteam on meets.meet_hometeam=hteam.team_id 
 LEFT JOIN teams as ateam on meets.meet_awayteam=ateam.team_id 
 LEFT JOIN teams as altloc on (meets.meet_altloc=altloc.team_id and meets.meet_altloc!='')
 WHERE meet_date between ($now+(4*86400)) and ($now+(5*86400) or meets.meet_id='2')
```

Then in your PHP, just call it by the alias you chose: `$var->hometeam_town, $var->hometown_id, $var->awayteam_town` etc...